# How to correct timestamp after time linear interpolation (inttime) in cdo

Tags: nco, cdo-climate

I have a dataset at hourly timesteps and I am interpolating it to 30-min with 'inttime' in cdo. However, the timestamp outputted is not correct, it is just duplicated from the original data. How can I correct that using cdo (or nco)?

I am interpolating the data with 'cdo inttime,date,time,inc ifile.nc ofile.nc'.

This is what I have after the interpolation...
2000-01-01 01:*00*:00, 2000-01-01 01:*00*:00, 2000-01-01 02:*00*:00, 2000-01-01 02:*00*:00, etc.

But this is what I want to have after the interpolation...
2000-01-01 01:*00*:00, 2000-01-01 01:*30*:00, 2000-01-01 02:*00*:00, 2000-01-01 02:*30*:00, etc.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Cheers,
M.

Comment: tricky, cdo shifttime shifts *all* steps in the file, so that won't help. I've not used that function in cdo myself.  Weird it doesn't handle the time step in a sensible way, I wonder if it is even a bug? I corrected your question tag by the way

Comment: Can you clarify the question? `cdo inttime,date,time,inc ifile.nc ofile.nc` is not a valid CDO call. What was your actual call? The issue described should not occur, as far as I know. It looks like ofile.nc is just the original data copied

Answer (score 2):

You can correct the time variable after its mis-interpolation by assigning it to an arithmetically increasing array with [ncap2](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap_arr), e.g., if units are hours since start day, then something like the following...

```
ncap2 -s 'time=array(1.0,0.5,$time)' in.nc out.nc
```

`ncap2` can also interpolate using GSL, but the CDO formulation appears much simpler so I wouldn't bother trying to change that.

Comment: Thanks a ton Charlie!